# Java erasure error with unrelated generic in method

Tags: java, generics

I've read the other questions related to erasures, but I'm still not clear why I get the compile error in the class below.  The other questions involve methods that actually use the generic type, whereas I'm just trying to implement a method using the exact same signature.  Can anyone explain?

Compile error -> name clash: bar(java.util.Set) in test.Baz and bar(java.util.Set) in test.Foo have the same erasure, yet neither overrides the other

```
import java.util.Set;

public class test {
  public interface Foo<T> {
    public void bar(Set<String> s);
  }

  public abstract class Baz implements Foo {
    public void bar(Set<String> s) {}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Did you intend for Baz to implement `Foo<String>` or to implement `Foo<T>` or to implement `Foo`?  What you typed was the last of those, but this means that Bar implements the "ungenerified" Foo.  The weird thing is that this turns off generics in `Foo`'s definition entirely, not just the generics that have to do with `T`.

That means that inside `Baz`, the method `Foo.bar` takes a parameter of just `Set`, not `Set<String>`.

You want either:

```
public abstract class Baz implements Foo {
  public void bar(Set s) {}
}
```

or

```
public abstract class Baz<T> implements Foo<T> {
  public void bar(Set<String> s) {}
}
```

or

```
public abstract class Baz implements Foo<Void> {
  public void bar(Set<String> s) {}
}
```

Depending on what you're trying to do.

Comment: hehe, I was going to try to explain why it was wrong too...but I don't really know why. :(

Comment: Well, you got your answer in several minutes before I got mine in, so you grabbed the "look at the one answer there and if it's even vaguely right upvote it" bump, which is worth from +2 to +7, depending on question and time of day.  (And you know your answer won't compile either, right?)

Comment: Baz is abstract, so I was going to let the concrete subclasses choose T.  Your second option is probably the closest to what I meant to do.  And yes, it is weird that it turns of all generics, instead of just T.  That's what had me stumped.  Thanks.

Comment: I know I'm digging up the dead, but can someone point me to why this happenes (that is why all generics are switched off)

Answer (score 4):

I think you need to change this:

```
public abstract class Baz implements Foo {
```

to this:

```
public abstract class Baz implements Foo<T> {
```

That way you properly override function `Foo`.